# SSRS search text box (parameter) dependent dropdown lists cascading filter - SQL Reporting

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I am having a situation where I can't proceed further with my report.

I have 2 parameters and the first parameter is a search text and user allowed to enter multiple search values and  then the second parameter will get loaded and in the dataset to get loaded.

1. `ReportParameter1` - user should give text need to be search. It should allow multiple values.
2. `ReportParameter2` - (Multi Selection dropdown) - If we pass single value in `ReportParameter1` it is showing related dropdown list in `ReportParameter2`. If multiple values are given in `ReportParameter1` it should load all the values in `ReportParameter2` related to the search words but it is not returning any dropdownlist.

Any help will be highly appreciated and I hope the explanation make sense?

Thanks,

For passing one parameter:

[image: screenshot1]

passing multiple values:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Can you post the SQL for dataset for parameter 2?

Comment: SELECT party.party_name FROM apps.hz_parties party WHERE UPPER(party.party_name) LIKE  '%'||upper(:ReportParameter1)||'%'

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: you need a sql server side split function and your end users have to agree to use comma as seperator. Your call to this split function will look something like this...
party.party_name IN (SELECT Split FROM [dbo].[ufn_Split](@param_1, ',')) ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `IN` operator for multiple parameter values.

```
SELECT party.party_name 
FROM apps.hz_parties party 
WHERE UPPER(party.party_name) IN(:ReportParameter1)
```

---

The other option would be to filter the `tablix`.

> Note: Report processing time will be longer for a tablix filter.

[image: screenshot]